# Is the concept of an $H$ object still interesting, when we have the $\infty$-version of it?

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, universal-algebra, higher-algebra

Recently I got acquainted with [$\infty$-algebraic theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28%E2%88%9E%2C1%29-algebraic+theory#homotopy_algebras). I expect $\infty$-algebraic objects (of ordinary Lawvere theories) in $\infty\text{-}\mathrm{Groupoid}$ to behave much better than algebraic objects in the homotopy category (called [$H$-objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/H-space)). In a certain sense, this is a more correct concept. So my question:

> Are H-objects interesting in their own right or is it just some random/pathological extension of the 1-truncation of those objects that really play a fundamental role in modern mathematics?

Or like this:

> If we initially thought ∞-categorically, would we invent H-objects? Why / in connection with what?.

The answer to my question could be a list of broad interesting contexts in which exactly $H$-objects appear, but not their higher versions. Or some justification that the concept has really lost its independent value and its role has become auxiliary.

Comment: "Is there not a natural model structure on the category of algebraic objects in a homotopy category?" - I think this is a great question as opposed to your titular question. $H$-objects are often  more difficult to study, this does not make them "incorrect", but rather interesting.

Comment: In regards to this question, model categories are usually defined to admit finite (co)limits. Categories of $H$-objects have very few limits, usually only (co)products.

Comment: Indeed, there are almost no limits and colimits, sorry, for some reason I did not think about it. In fact, I didn't like my question at all when I finished it. But I definitely have a sense of the question, sounding along the lines of "are H-objects interesting in their own right or is it just some random/pathological extension of the 1-truncation of those objects that really play a fundamental role in modern mathematics". Or like this: "if we initially thought $\infty$-categorically, would we invent H-objects? Why / in connection with what?".

Comment: I decided to bet that I would be lucky to be understood and asked my question. But I think that I myself will gradually figure out the answer for myself. So if my question does not meet with interest, then I will calmly relate to its closure.

Comment: Regarding the "model structure on the category of $H$-objects", I actually meant: is there a model category $M$ "similar" to $T[\mathrm{sSet}]$ such that $\mathrm{Ho } M = T[\mathrm{Hmpt}]$ (or maybe we can take $T[\mathrm{sSet}]$ itself?). The "similarity" condition here is more or less about the fact that the model category will have the same excellent categorical properties (so trivial model structures were not suitable: even if $T[\mathrm{Hmpt}]$ were bicomplete, it is far from the category of algebraic objects in topos).

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by algebraic object or algebraic-homotopy object but H-spaces (if this is what you mean by H-objects) are not wrong at all.

Comment: I edited my question significantly. I hope you like it more this way. The question about the model structure (in its latest version) seems interesting to me, but it is not related to the current version of the main question, so I removed it.

Comment: @AivazianArshak as you probably know, not all H-spaces are A-infinity spaces. For some of them that’s all the structure you have.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, but slightly too long for a comment.

The main thing I wanted to say is that there is no "correct" or "incorrect" formalization, they just serve different purposes.

For instance (grouplike) $H$-spaces are enough for some purposes (such as proving that a space is simple) and because this is a very minimal amount of structure, this can make them very handy. On the other hand, they cannot be delooped, unlike grouplike $A_\infty$-spaces, and they don't have a very workable homotopy theory, unlike (grouplike) $A_\infty$-spaces.

For your specific subquestion, it's not easy to answer in full generality: the trivial Lawvere theory has very nice up-to-homotopy models, and some simple examples might also have a nice model category that models them. Here is one way to possibly prove that something is *not* the homotopy category of a suitably nice model category: if $M$ is a model category, $ho(M)$ admits weak pullbacks, that is, for every cospan $A\to B \leftarrow C$, there is a cone $P\to A,C$ which satisfies a version of the universal property of a pullback, but without uniqueness. Indeed, the homotopy pullback satisfies this property.

I want to guess that in many (most ?) cases, for a nontrivial Lawvere theory $T$, $Mod_T(\mathrm{Ho})$ does not have weak pullbacks; but I'm not sure how to prove that, as I'm not sure what the correct way to say "many cases" is.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with $A_n$ and $A_\infty$, but do $H$-objects (with some choice of homotopy) lie between some $A_{n-1}$ and $A_n$?

Comment: @Z.M a choice of a binary product and a homotopy for associativity is $A_3$.

Comment: But without associativity (which is often what is meant by $H$-space), it is $A_2$ (in fact, $H$-space is often the unital version of $A_2$)